# Vert.x's Future gets null value because handler is fired before the future's complete

Tags: java, asynchronous, future, vert.x, vertx-httpclient

I am trying to understand Vert.x framework and I have a task to create HTTP server which will perform simple mathematical computations and a client which will send multiple requests to that server. I need to count the time needed to send all requests and get responses. I managed to create the client, the server and to send requests and retrieve responses, but I have a problem with measuring the time needed to do these operations.

My client verticle has the following `start()` method:

```
@Override
    public void start() throws Exception {

        WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);

        IntStream.range(0, MathClientApp.REQUEST_NUMBER)
            .forEach(i -> Arrays.stream(Operations.values()).forEach(operation -> {

                client
                    .get(8080, "localhost", operation.getPath())
                    .addQueryParam("numbers", StringUtils.join(numbers, ","))
                    .send(result -> {
                        if (result.succeeded()) {
                            Double mathResult = Double.parseDouble(result.result().bodyAsString());
                            if (mathResult.equals(operation.result(numbers))) {
                                System.out.println("Result: " + result.result().bodyAsString() + " OK!");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Result: " + result.result().bodyAsString() + " WRONG!");
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Communication failed.");
                        }
                    });
            }));
    }
```

`Operations` is an enum with all of the mathematical operations the server can do.

Now, I figured out that I need to set starting time before sending a request to the client and then to set ending time on `send()` callback. Because operations are asynchronous, the ending time may not be set in the moment of getting it to count difference, so I thought this ending time needs to be `Future` object. So I added some code:

```
@Override
    public void start() throws Exception {

        WebClient client = WebClient.create(vertx);

        IntStream.range(0, MathClientApp.REQUEST_NUMBER)
            .forEach(i -> Arrays.stream(Operations.values()).forEach(operation -> {

                Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Future<Long> endTime = Future.future(future -> {
                    times.add(future.result() - startTime);
                });

                client
                    .get(8080, "localhost", operation.getPath())
                    .addQueryParam("numbers", StringUtils.join(numbers, ","))
                    .send(result -> {
                        if (result.succeeded()) {
                            endTime.complete(System.currentTimeMillis());
                            Double mathResult = Double.parseDouble(result.result().bodyAsString());
                            if (mathResult.equals(operation.result(numbers))) {
                                System.out.println("Result: " + result.result().bodyAsString() + " OK!");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Result: " + result.result().bodyAsString() + " WRONG!");
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Communication failed.");
                        }
                    });
            }));
    }
```

My understanding is the following: before each request I take the current time in miliseconds and create `Future` for ending time with a handler that will subtract these times when ending time will appear. Then the request is sent and when a response is received ending time is set, so handler method of the `Future` is called, times are subtracted and saved to a list of all times from all requests.

But I get NullPointerException in the `Future`'s handler method. It's executing before the call to the server so the value is not present yet. I can't understand why and the official documentation for Vert.x doesn't say exactly how to use this `Future` feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if the future was completed inside the handler method. So it would look something like this:

```
Future<Long> endTime = Future.future(future -> {
    if(future.succeeded()) {
        times.add(future.result() - startTime);
    }
});
```